# How to extrac/print the code of an embedded function in a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, pickle

#### Topic

I sometimes put a function inside a dictionary. I also save (via pickle) this dictionary for later usage.

#### My problem is:

I want to know what exact code I have put´ into this dictionary. So I want to review the stored code.

#### My question:

Is it possible to extract/print the python code of the stored function?

##### Code Example

```
def my_function(a,b):
return a**2+b

my_dict={}
my_dict["func"]=my_function

print(my_dict["func"](1,2))
```

Results in:

> 5

##### What I have tried:

As I am working with Jupyter-Notebook i can inspect the function (shift+Tab)
and see the "File" of the function:
In this example it is:

> Signature: my_function(a, b)
> Docstring:  File:
> c:\users\my_win11_username\appdata\local\temp\ipykernel_12708\1360562146.py
> Type:      function

Unfortunately the file or even the path does not exist on my computer (or very well hidden). --> I cannot access it

#### Possible workaround I have identified:

It might be possible to store the code (as string or screenshot) inside the dictionary as well. But that is error prone and most likely not the solution I am aiming for.

---

## EDIT:

As pointed out in the comments the idea of storing functions in dictionaries and pickling them **does not work**!

### --> question closed

Comment: If I can calculate it should print 3 not 5.

Comment: The value in your dictionary is merely a reference to the function. It does not contain the function's implementation. If you serialise (pickle) your dictionary in one script (where the function is defined) then try to load the pickled file in another script, you will not be able to invoke the function. You'll get an AttributeError because the function (my_function) will not be found

Comment: You can use a doc string in your function and than `print(my_function.__doc__)`

Comment: You are both right:
the correct result should be 5, not 3.  

More important:
It actual **does not work**, as indicated by @CtrlZ ! If I open the pkl file in a new instance I get the mention Attribute Error.
What I do a lot, is storing np.RegularGridInterpolator "files" as pickle and adding them to dictionaries! Then pickle again. This works well. So I was assuming that I can do the same with functions.  

I guess I have to go for class objects to get a behavior somehow like that.